# Find files in a directory and list them

Tags: command-line, find, ls

I'm in a directory containing several sites directories. All these sites have a `logs/`
directory. I wish to `find` and list the files under each `logs/` directory with the `-ls` parameter.

Comment: Could you please describe a bit the directory tree structure and the expected output? Otherwise I'd suggest a basic `ls www/*/logs/*`

Comment: So basically I typed `ls -la /var/www/vhosts/*/logs/*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would list the logs with a simple call to `ls` in your case:

```
ls -la /var/www/vhosts/*/logs/*
```